# Grouping asynchronous functions to run

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a code that outputs numbers from 1 to 10:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep
    
async def main(k):
    print(k)
    await sleep(1)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_objects = list()
    count_group = 3

    for i in range(1, 11):
        list_objects.append(i)

    list_func = [main(x) for x in list_objects]

    loop = get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(gather(
        *list_func
    ))
```

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

It is noticeable that in the example above, 10 functions are simultaneously launched at once. How can I fix the code so that the number of concurrent launched functions **main()** is equal to **count_group**? That is, immediately the output should be *123*, then *456*, then *789* and at the end *10*.

Comment: Your best options are probably to call `gather` after eat batch completes or introduce another coroutine that oversees each batch and gather those instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your tasks into run groups and `gather()` each group one by one.

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_group = 3

    list_func = [ main(x) for x in range(1,11) ]
    run_groups = [ list_func[i:i+count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]
    loop = get_event_loop()

    for rg in run_groups:
        loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
```